# How to select multiple objects in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have code which works fine

```
$('#' + file.id + 'tdp').remove();
$('#' + file.id + 'tdr').remove();
```

I would like to refactor code to make it less using multiple selector like this

```
$('#' + file.id + 'tdp', '#' + file.id + 'tdr').remove();
```

Unfortunately it does not work, why?

Comment: look at the answer provided by Quincy. His answer would effectively render a string "#0tdp, #0tdr" that would be used to locate and remove elements with the IDs specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma should be within the selector string

```
$('#' + file.id + 'tdp , #' + file.id + 'tdr').remove();
```

Answer (score 5):

The comma should be part of the selector string. Use this instead:

```
$('#' + file.id + 'tdp, #' + file.id + 'tdr').remove();
```

Alternatively, you could use `.add()`:

```
$('#' + file.id + 'tdp').add('#' + file.id + 'tdr').remove();
```

It’s up to you to decide which one is more readable.

Comment: .add() is exactly what I was hoping existed but I couldn't find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your comma between the element selectors is at the code level rather than being part of the selector string. This means that the JavaScript engine interprets the second part as the second parameter to the `$` function.

Personally, I would leave the two statements as separate statements as it is easier to read, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example, you could also use something like this:

```
$('[id^="'+file.id+'td"]').remove();
```

Not sure though that this is more readable and efficient, just another possible solution.

[jQuery Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)